# Why doesn't PHP catch a "Class not found" error?

Tags: php, try-catch

In the following example, if the class does not exist, I want to catch the error and create a `Null` class instead.

But in spite of my try/catch statements, PHP simply tells me `Class 'SmartFormasdfasdf' not found`.

**How can I get PHP to catch the 'class not found' error?**

```
<?php
class SmartFormLogin extends SmartForm {
    public function render() {
        echo '<p>this is the login form</p>';
    }
}

class SmartFormCodeWrapper extends SmartForm {
    public function render() {
        echo '<p>this is the code wrapper form</p>';
    }
}

class SmartFormNull extends SmartForm {
    public function render() {
        echo '<p>the form "' . htmlentities($this->idCode) . '" does not exist</p>';
    }
}

class SmartForm {

    protected $idCode;

    public function __construct($idCode) {
        $this->idCode = $idCode;
    }

    public static function create($smartFormIdCode) {
        $className = 'SmartForm' . $smartFormIdCode;
        try {
            return new $className($smartFormIdCode);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return new SmartFormNull($smartformIdCode);
        }
    }
}

$formLogin = SmartForm::create('Login');
$formLogin->render();
$formLogin = SmartForm::create('CodeWrapper');
$formLogin->render();
$formLogin = SmartForm::create('asdfasdf');
$formLogin->render();
?>
```

## Solution:

Thanks @Mchl, this is how I solved it then:

```
public static function create($smartFormIdCode) {
  $className = 'SmartForm' . $smartFormIdCode;
  if(class_exists($className)) {
    return new $className($smartFormIdCode);
  } else {
    return new SmartFormNull($smartFormIdCode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because it's a fatal error. Use class_exists() function to check if class exist.

Also: PHP is not Java - unless you redefined default error handler, it will raise errors and not throw exceptions.

Comment: I forgot, PHP try/get feature merely helps you build your own exception handling by enabling you to throw your own errors, but doesn't consequently catch errors itself as in C#/Java.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php for example on how to 'rewrite' all (except fatal) errors to exceptions. Also, as other suggested, since 5.3 you might want to use autoloader to throw an exception when a file containing given class is not found.

Comment: @Edward - it certainly lets you catch *exceptions*, but almost everything native to PHP doesn't throw Exceptions, just errors.  You can work around this easily by defining your own *error_handler* and having that throw Exceptions using ErrorException (see http://au.php.net/errorexception and the example there).  This easily switches PHP's native error system to a useful Exception based system that works quite nicely with throw/try/catch etc.

Answer (score 33):

Old question, but in PHP7 this is a catchable exception. Though I still think the `class_exists($class)` is a more explicit way to do it. However, you could do a try/catch block using the new `\Throwable` exception type:

```
$className = 'SmartForm' . $smartFormIdCode;
try {
    return new $className($smartFormIdCode);
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
    return new SmartFormNull($smartformIdCode);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to get more specific with what you are catching, you can catch the \Error type instead (tested to work in PHP 7.1). This would make your code more brittle to changes how the PHP language evolves, but also less likely to catch something you did not intend it to catch. If you have good automated tests, you should be able to get away with the more specific version because your tests would fail if PHP suddenly started throwing a different type for this.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

php >= 7.0

php can catch 'class not found' as  Throwable

```
try {
        return new $className($smartFormIdCode);
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
        return new SmartFormNull($smartformIdCode);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [class_exists](http://www.php.net/class_exists) to see if the class exists before you try and instantiate it.

Incidentally, if you're using a class autoloader, be sure to set the second arg to true.

Answer (score 0):

Because php emits fatal error when you ty to create new object of non existing class. To make it work you will need php >= 5.3 and [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) function, where you should try to look for file with class definition or throw your custom exception.

Comment: a) autoload is the wrong way to do it - see http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php and b) it doesn't require PHP 5.3

Comment: Throwing exceptions in autoloader does indeed require 5.3. ANd there's nothing 'wrong' about it as long as you know what you're doing (i.e. it's a bit silly to throw an exception when there are more autoloaders in autoload queue).

Comment: @El Yobo - can you elaborate what is wrong with autoload? spl function does the same, only difference is that it allows you to provide more functions to run in search for correct file. Ans as for b), as Mchl said, you will still need php 5.3 to make it throw an exception.