# Laravel 5.5 Try / Catch is not working it's execute the exception handle

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, try-catch, laravel-5.5

I am working with laravel 5.5 I have written a code with try and catch exception. But Try / catch is not manage exception handling. Exception execute on the `Exception/handle.php`

Here is code I am following

```
try {
 App\Models\justDoIt::find(1);
}  catch (\Exception $ex) {
       dd($ex);
       report($ex);
       return false;
}
```

I would like to know why catch is not executed and error is display from the `handle.php` in `report()`

Here is the handle.php code

```
public function report(Exception $exception) {
        echo "Handle";
        dd($exception);
        parent::report($exception);
    }
```

Result

```
Handle
FatalThrowableError {#284 ▼
  #message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Models\justDoIt' not found"
  #code: 0
  #file: "D:\xampp7\htdocs\homeexpert_nik\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php"
  #line: 21
  #severity: E_ERROR
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Result will show from the handle.php file.

Comment: You can use `JustDoIt::findOrFail`

Comment: @RutvijKothari I have tried to use FindOrFail but still I got exception from handle? why this is so? why it's not execute catch Exception

Comment: Class not found exception is handled differently in PHP. You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421320/why-doesnt-php-catch-a-class-not-found-error

Answer (score 8):

Your code is throwing an error, not an exception. You're trying to use a class that doesn't exist and PHP is complaining about it by throwing a `FatalThrowableError`.

In PHP 5, this code would have resulted in a fatal error message being rendered in the browser, however in PHP 7 (Which is required for Laravel 5.5), PHP now throws errors just like they were exceptions. This allows applications to catch these errors, just like exceptions using try/catch blocks.

The reason the error is escaping your try/catch block is that an error is not an `Exception`, or a child of it. The object being thrown is an `Error`. Both the `Exception` and `Error` classes implement a common interface, `Throwable`.

```
Throwable
- Exception
- Error
```

Laravel's exception handler is written to catch both of these classes in order to display the error page you're seeing.

If you were to change your code to the following, you would find that the `} catch (Throwable $e) {` block should be executed:

```
try {
    App\Models\justDoIt::find(1);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
   dd('Exception block', $ex);
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
   dd('Throwable block', $ex);
}
```

For more information on this, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php).

---

**An added extra:** If you're wondering what the issue is with your code, it's because you likely forgot to `use` your model class in your controller:

```
use App\Models\justDoIt;
```