# How to catch a fatal error both in PHP 7 and 8?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I have a PHP 7 script, that basically does this:

```php
try {
    $class = getClassFromSomewhere();
}
catch(Error $e) {
    if ("Class 'Main' not found" == $e->getMessage()) {
        echo 'Run "php generate-main-class" to generate the class.'.PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

To be clear: if the class I am looking for is "Main" and can't be found, I must display the text, else it's supposed to throw the exception anyway.

It works well with PHP 7, but PHP 8 does not catch the error. Instead, it shows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Main" not found in ...
```

How am I supposed to catch a "Class not found" fatal error in PHP 8 in a backwards compatible way?

Comment: What is the code inside `getClassFromSomewhere()`?

Comment: Having just tried it online with PHP 8, the message is `Class "Main" not found` - note the quotes. You are testing for `"Class 'Main' not found"`

Comment: Might be worth a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421320/why-doesnt-php-catch-a-class-not-found-error/4421332

Comment: @NigelRen, that's right! It's single quotes in PHP 7 and double in PHP 8. Please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference seems to be that PHP 8 uses double quotes round the class name -

```
Class "Main" not found
```

whereas it previously (as in your current code) used single quotes...

```
Class 'Main' not found
```

You could alternatively just check if the class exists prior to trying the code ([In PHP how can i check if class exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971997/in-php-how-can-i-check-if-class-exists)), which may be cleaner than causing an error.